# what is the diffrence inode bitmap and inode table

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext2

I am trying to understand the difference between inode bitmap and inode table (from ext2 file system documentation), but I am not getting it. Can any one explain?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bitmap just occupies one block and is a sequence of `0`s and `1`s where `0` means that the corresponding *inode* in the _inode_table_ is free and `1` specified that it's used.

The *inode table* is where the actual information about the inode is written and it occupies more than one block on the filesystem.

The *bitmap* technique is useful to quickly find free locations on the inode table (or data blocks) when modifying the filesystem.

On the hard drive, those sections would look like this:

```
 inode bitmap:
 11100011010010101...

 inode table:
 struct inode | struct inode | struct inode | struct inode | ...
```